# STM32F411RE clock selection option is not working

Tags: stm32f4

[image]

1:- Pack Keil.STM32F4xx_DFP.2.16.0: Required C 99, but current is C 90
2:- i cannot find why i am unable to set the clock for my stm32f411re.

these two issue which i am getting while creating the new project.

I have attached the image as well as the warning for your reference. thank you.